# Audio capture and playback works perfectly, only the first time?

Tags: java, audio, capture, playback, microphone

basically, I'm still very new to working with microphones and audio capture + playback in Java and this is my first attempt that I have been struggling/tinkering with now for a couple hours to no solution (It's a mashup of the official tutorial and snippets).

I created a barebone version of what I'm trying to implement, hoping that removing code would reveal where the problem lies, however, I still recieved the same error making me realise that there is something fundamentally wrong with my logic that I cannot see.

Here is the (only) Class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class CaptureDemo extends JFrame
{
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private JButton capture;
    private JButton stop;
    private JButton play;

    private boolean running;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream out;

    private Thread captureThread;
    private Thread playThread;
    private DataLine.Info info;
    private AudioFormat format;
    private TargetDataLine line;

    public CaptureDemo()
    {
        super ("Audio Capture/Playback Demo");
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI()
    {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        capture = new JButton("Capture");
        stop = new JButton("Stop");
        play = new JButton("Play");

        capture.setEnabled(true);
        stop.setEnabled(false);
        play.setEnabled(false);

        ActionListener captureListener =  new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                capture.setEnabled(false);
                stop.setEnabled(true);
                play.setEnabled(false);
                captureAudio();
            }
        };
        capture.addActionListener(captureListener);
        panel.add(capture, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        ActionListener stopListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                capture.setEnabled(true);
                stop.setEnabled(false);
                play.setEnabled(true);
                running = false;
            }
        };
        stop.addActionListener(stopListener);
        panel.add(stop, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        ActionListener playListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                playAudio();
            }
        };
        play.addActionListener(playListener);
        panel.add(play, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        this.add(panel);
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    }

    private void captureAudio()
    {

        try
        {
            if (captureThread != null && captureThread.isAlive() )
            captureThread.interrupt();

            format =  getFormat();  
            info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
            line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

            line.open(format);
            line.start();

            Runnable RunnerOne = new Runnable() 
            {
                int bufferSize = (int)format.getSampleRate() * format.getFrameSize();
                byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];

                public void run() 
                {
                    out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    running = true;
                    try 
                    {
                        while (running) {
                            int count = line.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                            if (count > 0)
                            out.write(buffer, 0, count);
                        }
                        out.close();
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            captureThread = new Thread (RunnerOne);
            captureThread.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    private void playAudio()
    {
        try 
        {
            if (playThread != null && playThread.isAlive() )
                playThread.interrupt();


            byte audio[] = out.toByteArray();
            InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(audio);
            format = getFormat();
            final AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(input, format, audio.length / format.getFrameSize());
            info = new DataLine.Info( SourceDataLine.class, format);

            final SourceDataLine Sline = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            Sline.open(format);
            Sline.start();

            //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="RUNNABLE FOR AUDIO PLAY">
            Runnable PlaySoundRunnable = new Runnable()
            {
                int bufferSize = (int) format.getSampleRate() * format.getFrameSize();
                byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];

                public void run()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        int count;
                        while ((count = ais.read (buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                            if (count > 0) {
                                Sline.write(buffer, 0, count);
                            }
                        }
                        Sline.drain();
                        Sline.close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            playThread = new Thread(PlaySoundRunnable);
            playThread.start();
            //</editor-fold>    

        }    
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }

    private AudioFormat getFormat()
    {
        float sampleRate = 32000;
        int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
        int channels = 1;
        boolean signed = false;
        boolean bigEndian = true;
        return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed, bigEndian);
    }








    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        JFrame demo = new CaptureDemo();
        demo.pack();
        demo.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

Ok alright, so heres the problem: The program works exactly as I want it to on the first run, capturing the audio when pressing the capture button, stopping the capture when clicking the stop button and finally playing it when pressing the play button. Perfect.

However, the problem comes in when you attempt to capture again (without re-running the program) which throws an exception:

```
Error: line with format PCM_UNSIGNED 32000.0 Hz, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame,  not supported.

javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: line with format PCM_UNSIGNED 32000.0 Hz, 8 bit, mono, 1 bytes/frame,  not supported.
    at com.sun.media.sound.DirectAudioDevice$DirectDL.implOpen(DirectAudioDevice.java:513)
    at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:124)
    at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractDataLine.open(AbstractDataLine.java:156)
    at CaptureDemo.captureAudio(CaptureDemo.java:93)
    at CaptureDemo.access$300(CaptureDemo.java:14)
    at CaptureDemo$1.actionPerformed(CaptureDemo.java:52)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
```

Any Ideas?

Ps. I'm just starting out with java, would appreciate if you point out other bad practices I do :)

EDIT:
I managed to finally resolve the issue, stupidly I was not first closing the line before recreating and opening it, the line would still be in use but somehow throw a format unsupoorted error...

```
if (line != null && line.isOpen() )
   line.close()
```

Comment: check that the playable object isn't still active. you may have to destroy it and make a new instance

Comment: @PaulBastide, Will do in the meantime

Comment: @PaulBastide, you're response led me to an answer, many thanks.